# grep pattern match with begin and end

Tags: grep

I have the following text (single line) returned from a call to an API:

```
data=$(gcloud dns record-sets list --zone=production-internal | grep proj-name-name-dp)

 echo $data 

proj-name-name-dp.int.proj-name.abc.title.com.  CNAME  300    proj-name-name-dp.int.proj-name.abc.title.com.
```

However I would like to get just proj-name-name-dp.int.proj-name.abc.title.com
Everything from the dot after com should not be stored in data variable.

grep -o didn't help.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok with `awk` then could you please try following.

```
data=$(gcloud dns record-sets list --zone=production-internal | awk '/proj-name-name-dp/{sub(/\.com.*/,".com")} 1')
```